# Why highlight answered questions instead of unanswered ones?

Tags: feature-request, design

I feel that SO gives too much visual weight to answered questions in the lists. Consider this:

[image: Stats of questions in list]

1. Those big green squares on the **answered questions** steal the visitor's attention from what actually needs it: **unanswered questions.**
2. Why highlight something with answers… when they are not even accepted? It almost looks like that the issue has been taking care of. *Green => it's ok, we're all good here*

---

I would suggest only two levels of importance: **resolved** vs. **unresolved questions**.
You could either

- *de-emphasize resolved questions*, or
- *highlight unresolved questions*.

Comment: What do more people come here for: to find a solution to their problem, or to answer questions? From all evidence I've seen, it's very much the former. In that case, you optimize for those visitors by highlighting answered questions, because only those can have a chance of helping people in search of solutions.

Comment: @BradLarson I would think that people who are _reading the home page_ or a _list of questions_ are much more likely to be looking for something to answer. It seems that people who are trying to find an answer to their question are either going directly to a question or asking their own question.

Comment: Is anybody seriously having trouble locating the unanswered questions in the questions list? That seems very hard to believe. And what Brad says - the majority of users is likely to be looking for answered questions really

Comment: @BradLarson: you're right, to find a solution to **their own question**. It's unlikely that they will find them on the front page, though. Unless they are on a search page, highlighting others' answered questions is irrelevant to those users. When I look at look at those lists I look for something that isn't already solved.

Comment: @Pëkka: It's not an issue of *locating stuff.* You can even locate the "question feed" in this page, but you would have a problem if that was front and center, wouldn't you? Maybe if a random question had a bright red background you'd wonder why that is. It's a matter of usability and sensibleness (for lack of better terms)

Comment: Well, as has been pointed out, it is not necessarily as straightforward as you say. There are good arguments for favouring answered stuff visually over the unanswered.